# How to suppress 'Categories' list in mediawiki mobile footer

Tags: mediawiki

The list of a page's categories do not appear in a desktop browser, but do appear at the bottom of the page on mobile.

I use categories to generate DynamicPageLists and for internal tracking that aren't for human consumption,so I don't want to show them to users.

How can I disable it on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hide them with CSS

```
#catlinks {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Works great, though it still wastes time in genertaing the list and sending it to the user, but...  Thanks.